# Are values of environment variables case-sensitive?

Tags: java, environment-variables

I have a job that gets new records from an application then saves it to its local database. However, it's not seeing the new record.

I checked the job and its properties, specifically, the environment.properties and it looks like this:

VARIABLE_NAME=variable_value

The value of the variables don't have quotation marks. I wonder if the values inside the variables are case sensitive? Because the application that the job gets new records from has values that have a combination of upper and lowercase.

Comment: For which OS? Windows? Linux? Mac OSX?

Comment: That question is rather strange. The values itself can't be case sensitive or insensitive. It depends on the system/service/program which reads the values and interpret it.

Comment: Hi @EricGreen, it's for Unix.

Comment: Hi @AndyTurner, environment variables are used for the parameters.

Comment: I don’t think you’re using the term “environment variables” correctly.  That’s just a Java properties file that happens to be named environment.properties.  Environment variables are something provided by the underlying operating system;  they do not reside in a properties file.

Answer (score 6):

In general, the **values** of environment variables are case-preserving. Whether they are case-sensitive, is likely to depend on operating system and how they are used.

It's the code that uses those environment variables that may, or may not, be case sensitive. So the answer to your question depends on what uses it. Once they are given to code and converted to string type in any particular language, it all depends on how they are used.

Is it used as a file path on windows? Then it's very likely to be case insensitive (unless you do some special changes in windows registry), simply because file paths on windows are case insensitive. Is it for interaction with database? Then ask yourself is the database is case sensitive.

If you are comparing 2 environment variables in shell script (batch, bash or anything else), it's also likely to depend on how exactly it's done. For example `IF` in a batch script by default is case sensitive, unless given the `/I` option.

On linux, a good general assumption would be that it's all case sensitive unless specified otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

"application that the job gets new records from" has to be changing the strings (provided it's getting the input from the environment). environment variables have nothing to do with case-sensitivity - they contain exactly what you assign to them.

Answer (score 1):

Linux is very case-sensitive.

Windows is sort-of case sensitive.  I learned this while looking into this question:

[Cannot set %PATH% in windows from boost::process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75445876/cannot-set-path-in-windows-from-boostprocess/75446143#75446143)

In `cmd.exe` you can do this:

```
SET PATH=%PATH%;C:/MyPath
```

That will append `C:/MyPath` to the `Path` environment variable.

However, if you use Microsoft's [`SetEnvironmentVariable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setenvironmentvariable) to set `PATH`, you'll actually just create a new environment variable called `PATH` which is independent of the system-variable `Path`.

Comment: "*if you use Microsoft's `SetEnvironmentVariable` to set `PATH`, you'll actually just create a new environment variable called `PATH` which is independent of the system-variable `Path`*" - are you sure about that? Because Windows environment variables are NOT case sensitive.