# Cannot set %PATH% in windows from boost::process

Tags: c++, boost

I have a program which works great on Linux, but fails to preserve some of `%PATH%` on Windows.  Here's an example:

parent.cpp

```cpp
#include <boost/process.hpp>

int main()
{
    auto this_env = boost::this_process::environment();
    boost::process::environment env = this_env; // make a copy to avoid changing the orig

    env["TESTVAR"]  = "Test12";   // Confirm we can set a variable
    env["TESTVAR"] += "Test34";   // Confirm we can append
    env["PATH"]    += "C:\\Users\\"; // Confirm we can append to PATH

    boost::process::child c(
        boost::process::exe = "./child.exe",
        boost::process::env = env
    );
    c.wait();
}
```

child.cpp

```
#include <boost/process.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    auto env = boost::this_process::environment();

    std::cout << "TESTVAR = " << env["TESTVAR"].to_string() << std::endl
              << "PATH = " << env["PATH"].to_string() << std::endl;
}
```

Output on Linux (good):

```
$ g++ parent.cpp -o parent.exe
$ g++ child.cpp  -o child.exe
$ echo PATH = $PATH
PATH = /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
$ ./parent.exe
TESTVAR = Test12:Test34
PATH = /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:C:\Users\
                                          PATH is augmented! ~~~~~^
```

Output on Windows (bad):

```
$ x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix-g++ parent.cpp -o parent.exe -lwsock32 -lboost_filesystem-mt-x64
$ x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix-g++ child.cpp  -o child.exe  -lwsock32
$ scp parent.exe child.exe user@windows:
$ ssh user@windows
> echo %PATH%
C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;...

> parent.exe
TESTVAR = Test12:Test34
PATH = C:\Users\
        ^~~~ Path is replaced!
```

Is this a bug in `boost::process`, a feature of Windows, or is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: On Windows paths are separated with a semicolon but on Linux its separated with a colon. Maybe some bug in boost, which version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

There appears *some* case-sensitivity in windows environment variables.  By changing `child.cpp` to this, we can see all environment variables:

```
#include <boost/process.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    auto env = boost::this_process::environment();

    for (auto it : env )
        std::cout << it.get_name() << " = " << it.to_string() << std::endl;
}
```

The output contains:

```
Path = C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;...
TESTVAR = Test12;Test34
PATH = C:\Users\
```

If we change `parent.cpp` from :

```
env["PATH"] += "C:\\Users\\";
```

to

```
env["Path"] += "C:\\Users\\";
```

we get the correct output on Windows:

```
Path = C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;...;C:\Users\
TESTVAR = Test12;Test34
```

While `cmd.exe` can set/get path insensitively (`SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\\Users\\`), the API used by boost is case-sensitive.  Strange!

Comment: "*the API used by boost is case-sensitive*" - which API is that, exactly? Windows environment variables are NOT case-sensitive.

Comment: Looked deeper into Boost's implementation.  It uses [SetEnvironmentVariableA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processenv/nf-processenv-setenvironmentvariablea) (or the W variant).  It doesn't say anything in the documentation about case-sensitivity, but how else could you explain the `Path`/`PATH` output observed on Windows?

Comment: It's an MCVE, so it should be easy enough to reproduce. I'm curious if anyone sees alternative behavior.  Maybe it's a problem with the mingw cross-compiler I'm using, who knows?

Comment: If I'm reading boost's code correctly, `boost::process::environment::operator[]` is case-sensitive, so `env["PATH"] += ...` doesn't update the existing `Path` variable, it creates a new `PATH` variable. Internally, `environment` just stores a list of strings, and on Windows `boost::process::child` creates a new OS environment block from those strings and passes it as-is to the child process, which is why both `Path` and `PATH` variables appear in its output. `SetEnvironmentVariable(A|W)` is not involved in this operation. This is clearly a bug in boost, not in Windows.